# Generating time series for everyday's am9:00 to pm2:00

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to generatie time series from `am9:00 to pm2:00` everyday

My current time series generated from `min(ticktime)` to `max(ticktime)`

But I want to scope the series to `everyday's am8:59 to pm3:00`

how to do it ?

#### I  tried to generate time between `1:11 ~ 1:15`, But it didn't stop by  **1:15**

```
      SELECT generate_series
      (
        date_trunc('second', min(ticktime)) ,
        date_trunc('second', max(ticktime)) ,
        interval '1 sec'
      ) AS ticktime FROM czces  
        WHERE
        (date_part('hour', ticktime) >= 1 AND  date_part('minute', ticktime) > 10  )    
        AND  (date_part('hour', ticktime) <= 1 AND  date_part('minute', ticktime) <= 15 )
```

#### I tried another solution but the outputed generating series still not under the BETWEEN interval.

#### Please check the result the series not stopped by **1:01 am**

```
      SELECT generate_series
      (
        min(ticktime)::timestamp,
        max(ticktime)::timestamp,
         '1 minute'::interval
      ) AS ticktime FROM czces  
      where ticktime::time between '00:01 am'::time AND '1:01 am'::time


      ~~~~
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just add the appropriate where clause, no?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Thanks for your updates, but it still not works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate `where` clause.

Examples of the syntax to use:

```
select dt
from generate_series(
  now()::date - interval '1 day',
  now()::date + interval '1 day',
  '1 hour'
) as dt
where dt::time between '9:00 am'::time and '2:00 pm'::time;

select t
from generate_series(
  now()::timestamptz(0) - interval '1 day',
  now()::timestamptz(0) + interval '1 day',
  '1 hour'
) as t
where t::time between '9:00 am'::time and '2:00 pm'::time;
```